# Store JSON Data into SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, syntax-error

Can anyone please confirm what the issue with the code. Am trying to store json data into sql but its showing error. Below is the code

```
DECLARE @json varchar(max)='
    {
      "BusinessEntityID":1,
      "NationalIDNumber":"295847284",
      "JobTitle":"Chief Executive Officer",
      "BirthDate":"1969-01-29",
      "Gender":"M",
      "Contact":{"Home":"036/222-333","Mob":"064/3376222"}
   }   
';
 
SELECT * INTO Person
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH (BusinessEntityID int,
         NationalIDNumber int,
         JobTitle varchar(100),
         BirthDate varchar(200),
         Gender varchar(2),
         Contact varchar(max)
)
```

[image]

**Error Msg**: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.`

Comment: I have following version of sql server Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM)

Comment: @SalmanVadsarya you can use sql server 2019 but different sql server compatibility, check your database compatibility level

Comment: yes it done by changing a compatibility level. Thank you.

Comment: Side note: you probably want `Contact nvarchar(max) AS JSON`

Comment: thank you. For your suggestion will definitely change it.